# Opencv Codec Selection Dialog not showing

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I have following code

> CvVideoWriter* VideoWriter = cvCreateVideoWriter("D:\Save\filenme.mpeg",-1  ,  10, cvSize(nWidth,nHeight), 1);

I have tested this code in Windows but OpenCV Codec Selection Dialog not showing.

Comment: unrelated, but *please* do not use opencv's deprecated c-api, use the c++ one instead !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change *.mpeg to *.avi Like this

CvVideoWriter* VideoWriter = cvCreateVideoWriter("D:\Save\filenme.avi",-1 , 10, cvSize(nWidth,nHeight), 1);

Here is the 
[link](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/cvCreateVideoWriter-problem-to-select-Codec-td5980420.html)